# Http benchmark tool for testing with different post payload each time

Tags: apache, http, benchmarking, apachebench

Can you please recommend a http benchmark tool that can use a dynamic post payload on each request?

I want it to be able to do concurent requests and at the same time each request to be different?

I've tested with Apache Benchmark but couldn't be able to do that, I also tried with Curl multi, but statistics were awful to gather.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objective is to push load to apache web server then [apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a very good tool. However, it is not reliable for measuring the performance. JMeter can read from a [CSV file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), so you can build your POST data dynamically.